# make highcharts graph with data in json format, with 4-element array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, charts, highcharts

json data is of this type:

```
[["SSL Certificate Signed Using Weak Hashing Algorithm",4500,"98","10980"],["SSL Self-Signed Certificate",2000,"98","-1"],...]
```

I can correctly display the name (the first element) and the numeric value (second element).
I would like the third and fourth elements to appear along with the name.
I would also like to distinguish the bars with different colors based on the value of the third element. It's possible? How can I do?

This is the code I wrote:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
var options = {     
chart: {renderTo:'grafico1',type:'column'},     
series: [{    }] // Lascio vuoto   
};   

$.getJSON('json.json', function(data){    
options.series[0].data = data;     
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); 
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use jQuery to generate `category` array and 3 series arrays
2. Your third/forth values are not numeric, so they are parsed.

I create this jsFiddle and it works, check this:

https://jsfiddle.net/s87pg0ew/2/

javascript:

```js
var myJsonData = [["SSL Certificate Signed Using Weak Hashing Algorithm",4500,"98","10980"],["SSL Self-Signed Certificate",2000,"98","-1"]];

var categories = [];
var value1 = [];
var value2 = [];
var value3 = [];
$.each(myJsonData, function( index, value ) {
  categories.push(value[0]);
  value1.push(value[1]);
  value2.push(parseInt(value[2]));
  value3.push(parseInt(value[3]));
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Test'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Test'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: categories,
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Test y axis',
            align: 'high'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -40,
        y: 80,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor:
            Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || '#FFFFFF',
        shadow: true
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
                name: "type1",
        data: value1
    }, {
            name: "type2",
        data: value2
    }, {
            name: "type3",
        data: value3
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But that's not what I wanted to achieve. I probably explained myself badly.
I want the value of the third and fourth element of the array to appear in the label along with the first element.
Then I would like the bars to be of a different color, based on the value of the third element.
 for example, bars with a value of "98" of one color, and bars with a value of "99" of another.

Comment: @EpicBrozo96 Maybe you can draw a picture to show your example and we will get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `array.map` feature in the simply way to parse your data.

```
const mainData = [["SSL Certificate Signed Using Weak Hashing Algorithm",4500,"98","10980"],["SSL Self-Signed Certificate",2000,"98","-1"]];

const categories = mainData.map(d => d[0]);

const data1 = mainData.map(d => d[1]);
const data2 = mainData.map(d => parseInt(d[2]));
const data3 = mainData.map(d => parseInt(d[3]));
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/btv80h1q/

But I think that those operations should be done on the backend side.